# how to connect a web application to an aws iot

Tags: amazon-web-services, internet-of-things

I am trying to create an mqtt in aws iot and connect it with a web application. For this, i have logged in to AWS iot and created a thing. After creating I am getting an ARN as follows

```
arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:14257896542:thing/sample
```

Then I have created a certificate and policy as per the AWS documentation. Now, I go to the test module, subscribed to a topic `4/5/1` and on publishing to this channel, I am getting the message.

My question is, how can i access this from a web application ? From, settings, I can see an endpoint as follows.

```
a37gqesacnrdrdsds5dg.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication process with AWS-IOT makes it very complicated for apps to connect to MQTT broker.  There is a aws-iot-sdk for JavaScript, but because the app cannot present the cert files, you will need aws-sdk and must use AWS Cognito.  More details here: https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/developing-connected-applications-with-aws-iot-technical-301